# Django Multiple GenericRelation related_name in admin

Tags: python, django-admin

I'm tring to create a generic foreign key and reuse it multiple time inside the same model

The problem is that when I load the admin interface I got the 2 Inline fields that display the same data.

I tried to use an fk_name passing the related_name defined in the model but without luck

Here is the code any help is appreciate

## model.py:

```
class TranslatedCharField(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('object_id', 'lang')

    lang = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=LANGUAGES)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Evento(models.Model):
    slug = generic.GenericRelation(TranslatedCharField, related_name="slug")
    titolo = generic.GenericRelation(TranslatedCharField, related_name="title")
```

## admin.py:

```
class TranslatedSlugInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
    extra = 0
    model = TranslatedCharField
    verbose_name = "Slug"
    verbose_name_plural = "Slug"


class TranslatedTitoloInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
    extra = 1
    model = TranslatedCharField
    verbose_name = "Titolo"
    verbose_name_plural = "Titolo"


class EventoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
    TranslatedSlugInline,
    TranslatedTitoloInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Evento, EventoAdmin)
```

this is the result:
[image]

as you can see the list of TranslatedCharField is duplicated for the 2 relations

Comment: That's because you use two inlines with the same model. Are you trying to create a slug out of the translated text string?

Comment: it was just a test the real test is to use the same Content type more than 1 time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I'd reviewed the things a but and the result is the follow:

```
class TranslatedCharField(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
    relation_field = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('object_id', 'lang', 'relation_field')

    lang = models.CharField(verbose_name="lingua", max_length=255, choices=LANGUAGES)
    text = models.CharField(verbose_name="testo", max_length=255)


def translatedFieldInlineAdminFormFactory(relation_field, translatemodel):
    class TranslatedFieldInlineAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = translatemodel

        def clean(self):
            self.cleaned_data["relation_field"] = relation_field
            return self.cleaned_data

class TranslatedTabularInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TranslatedTabularInline, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form = translatedFieldInlineAdminFormFactory(self._relation_field_filter, self.model)

    extra = 1
    max_num = len(LANGUAGES)
    exclude = ('relation_field',)
    model = None
    _relation_field_filter = None
    return TranslatedFieldInlineAdminForm
```

In this way when I need multiple TranslatedCharField I do the following

on the admin:

```
class TranslatedSlugInline(TranslatedTabularInline):
    model = TranslatedCharField
    _relation_field_filter = "slug_event_portal"
    verbose_name = "Slug"
    verbose_name_plural = "Slug"

class TranslatedSlugInline(TranslatedTabularInline):
    model = TranslatedCharField
    _relation_field_filter = "slug2_event_portal"
    verbose_name = "Slug2"
    verbose_name_plural = "Slug2"
```

thanks to the clean method a specific _relation_field_filter is used for each inline 
this allow me at least to save them distinguished and retrive them useing the custom queryset
I'm still working on the Model of the Evento to retrive the specific set of values instead the whole related fields but I think I'm not too far now

Answer (score 0):

```
unique_together = ('object_id', 'lang')
```

I think you want

```
unique_together = ('content_type', 'object_id', 'lang')
```

because object_id is not unique across models.

```
slug = generic.GenericRelation(TranslatedCharField, related_name="slug")
titolo = generic.GenericRelation(TranslatedCharField, related_name="title")
```

"related_name" is how the TranslatedCharField can access in the other direction, i.e. by which attribute name you want it to access that Evento. "slug_event" and "title_event" more fitting.

Comment: if I use TranslatedCharField and use unique_together = ('content_type', 'object_id', 'lang') it will be impossible to use the TranslatedCharField more than 1 with an "Evento" model